# Searching for a RegEx to split a text in it words

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am searching for a RegularExpression to split a text in it words.
I have tested

```
Regex.Split(text, @"\s+")
```

But this gives me for example for

```
this (is a) text. and

this
(is
a)
text
and
```

But I search for a solution, that gives me only the words - without the (, ), . etc.
It should also split a text like

```
end.begin
```

in two words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off *matching the words* rather than splitting.

If you use `Split` (with `\W` as [Regexident suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9193643/87399)), then you could get an extra string at the beginning and end. For example, the input string `(a b)` would give you *four* outputs: `""`, `"a"`, `"b"`, and another `""`, because you're using the `(` and `)` as *separators.*

What you probably want to do is just match the words. You can do that like this:

```
Regex.Matches(text, "\\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value)
```

Then you'll get just the words, and no extra empty strings at the beginning and end.

Comment: Seeing as the `MatchCollection` returned by `Regex.Matches` contains only instances of `Match`, `.Cast<Match>` would bemore appropriate than `.OfType<Match>` because no type based filtering is required.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Regex.Split(text, @"\W+")
```

`\W` is the counterpart to `\w`, which means alpha-numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var text = "this (is a) text. and";

// to replace unwanted characters with space
text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "[(),.]", " ");

// to split the text with SPACE delimiter
var splitted = text.Split(null as char[], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

foreach (var token in splitted) 
{           
    Console.WriteLine(token);
}
```

---

See this [`Demo`](http://rextester.com/TAZP53024)