# I need to count letters in every word of string and display result as array, where do I have a mistake?

Tags: c#

I need to count letters in every word of string and display result as array, where do I have a mistake?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string s = textBox1.Text;
                char[] b = new char[s.Length];// string to array
                int count = 0;
                int[] result = new int [ Convert.ToInt32(s.Length) ];
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    b[i] = s[i];

                }
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (b[j] == ' ')
                    {
                        result[j] = count;
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < result.Length; k++)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = result[k].ToString();
                }
```

Comment: Sorry I beginner in coding

Comment: When you say "display result as array", what do you mean?

Comment: Well as a beginner there is no better time to start learning how to debug: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I mean I need to output array with amount letters in ewery word

Comment: Look up `string.Split` and `List<int>.ToArray` C# help topics.

Comment: think about what you want to do, then separate the tasks into small manageable chunks...for starters..if you need to count all the letters in each word , you need to split the string into each word, then count the letters. I would look up the Split function and the Foreach loop.   [link]http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your specific question, then give you a few suggestions on how you might improve the code.

**First**:
Your last three lines could be modified to output the results.

```
      for (int k = 0; k < result.Length; k++)
        {
            textBox2.Text = result[k].ToString();//BAD line
        }
```

There are three main problems (among others) with the line.

- every pass overwrites the text in your text box
- you are not filtering your result array
- you have not captured the final count if the last word does not have a space

**Try this:**

```
      for (int k = 0; k < result.Length; k++)
        {
           if (result[k]>0){
            textBox2.Text += result[k].ToString()+" ";
           }
        }
      if (count>0)textBox2.Text += result[k].ToString()+" ";
```

**Second**: *What happens if you have other whitespace characters, numbers, or punctuation but no space character?*

Consider splitting the text into words using RegEx - [Searching for a RegEx to split a text in it words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193620/searching-for-a-regex-to-split-a-text-in-it-words), then count the letters.

**Third**: What happens if your string contains thousands of letters but only a few hundred words? How might you reduce the size of the result array?

Consider creating the result array after you have identified the number of words - this is easy if you use RegEx to split your text into words.

Good luck Vasya!

Comment: This is good advice.  @Vasya, `string.Split` might be pretty useful for you to know as well if you are trying to deal with the easy case: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split